# R's S3 method dispatching does not work when sourcing package

Tags: r, oop, method-dispatch, r-environment

I am currently developing a package in R with the "help" of devtools. That is, the package is getting loaded into R studio via `load_all(path = ...)` in this stage and my functions from the R directory are made available. So far so good.
But when I try to implement a simple S3 hierarchy within my package, the dispatching will not work - it throws the following error:

> Error in UseMethod("generic_function", obj) :
> no applicable method for 'generic_function' applied to an object of class "c('data.frame', 'myclass')"

However, when I implement the same generic function as well as its methods and load them in the current environment explicitly the dispatching will work.

I cannot explain what is going on under the hood here. The dispatching will simply not work when I load the package but it works when "loading it on the fly" in the environment.

I appreciate your help.
BR

... as requested the code:

```
scaler <- function (solvertraj, ...) {
  UseMethod("scaler", solvertraj)
}

scaler.scale_multi <- function(solvertraj, ...){
  resls = list()
  ls = c("incumbant", "average.fitness")
  min_inc = min(solvertraj$incumbant)
  max_inc = max(solvertraj$incumbant)
  
  for(i in 1:length(ls)){
    tobe_scaled = ls[i]
    tmp = sapply(solvertraj[tobe_scaled], function(x){
      (x-min_inc) / (max_inc -min_inc)
    })
    resls[[i]] = tmp
  }
  #attr(solvertraj,'MIN_MAX_scaled') <<- TRUE
  return(resls)
} 

scaler.scale_other <- function(solvertraj, ...){
  res = list()
  plls = list()
  shapirols = list()
  resls = list()
  ls = c("incumbant", "average.fitness")
  
  for(i in 1:length(ls)){
    col = ls[i]
    # 1) shrink range
    tmp = sapply(solvertraj[col], function(x){
      x - min(solvertraj["incumbant"])
    })
    # 2) use natural logarithm
    tmp_2 = sapply(tmp, log)
    tmp_2[length(tmp_2)] <- 0L
    res[[i]] = tmp_2
    
    # TODO: fix
    plot_trans = plot(density(tmp_2))
    plls[[i]] = plot_trans
    
    tmp_test = shapiro.test(tmp_2)
    shapirols[[i]] <- tmp_test
  }
  
  resls = list.append(resls,
                      scales = res,
                      plots = plls,
                      shapirols = shapirols)

  #attr(solvertraj,'SHRINKAGE_scaled') <<- TRUE
  return(resls)
}
```

Comment: What does your `generic_function` look like? Or just show all the relevant code, otherwise troubleshooting is near impossible.

Comment: There you: btw, I have tried the functions and they work. The problem really drills down to the loading of the function... (I guess).

Much appreciate your help

Comment: I had a similar issue. You may need to export the dispatched methods:  `#' @export` above each

Comment: okay, could you just real quick elaborate on this? 
so basically doing:
#' @export
above all three functions will do it? why? 
Thank you I will try now

Comment: I have put [# '@export] but it still raises the same error. Do I have to include the NAMESPACE somehow?

Comment: `@export` is a roxygen2 tag, which exposes functions of a package to the user. If a function isn't exported, it can not be accessed by the `UseMethod()` dispatcher. In general if writing a package it is necessary to document your functions most commonly using roxygen tags. In RStudio you can insert a "standard" roxygen block using the shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + Alt + R`.

Comment: okay guys: thank you! I was putting roxygen 2 skeletons in all my R functions and converted them to .Rd files --> by this I got the NAMESPACE file and here I go: [S3method(scalerOwn,scale_multi)
S3method(scalerOwn,scale_other)]!

Comment: @SmokeyShakers it works. But I wonder why that should be done in case internally used generics. That really wired.

Comment: @IndranilGayen I totally agree. It's something I learned to do because it works, not because I understand why.

Answer (score 2):

The post is old, but this is an answer for people who'd face the same issue. I think the explanation might be you weren't using a proper workflow while using `devtools`:

1. code your method `print.myclass <- function(x, ...){}`
2. run `document()` **before** `load_all()` (this is how NAMESPACE will get properly updated)
3. run `load_all()`

If you skip `document()` and only run `load_all()`, you'll load your `print.myclass`, you'll be able to call it directly with `print.myclass(instance_myclass)` and get the intended result. `sloop::s3_dispatch(print(instance_myclass))` will confusingly tell you that it understands it should dispatch `print` to your method... but you'll get default `print` when calling `print(instance_myclass)`...

`#' @export` was probably not the problem here, even though S3 methods should be exported. It was probably due to incorrect NAMESPACE in your dev environment.